# variational form of fourth order elliptic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, variational-analysis

Given

$$
\alpha\Delta^2y+y=\alpha^{1/4}y_d-\alpha^{5/4}\Delta(f+u_d), \Omega
$$

$$
y=0, \alpha^{1/2}\Delta y+\alpha^{3/4}(f+u_d)=0
$$

I am trying to verify the regularity result as

$$
\alpha^{1/2}|y|_{H^2}+\|y\|_{L^2}\leq C\alpha^{1/4}(\|y_d\|_{L^2}+\alpha^{1/2}\|f+u_d\|_{L^2})
$$

The hint is to use the variational form but I am not sure how to proceed with

$$
(\Delta^2y,v)=(\Delta y\Delta y,v)=\int\frac{\partial y}{\partial n}\Delta y v -?
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an  incomplete answer providing the weak form. The regularity result is still giving me trouble. Let $y,v\in H^2_0(\Omega)$ and $(\cdot,\cdot) = (\cdot,\cdot)_{L^2(\Omega)}$. Then Green's identities yield

$$
\begin{aligned}
(\Delta^2y,v) = (\Delta y, \Delta  v) + \int_{\partial\Omega} v(\nabla\Delta u\cdot\hat{n}) - \Delta y(\nabla v\cdot \hat{n})ds.
\end{aligned}
$$

Applying this to the original PDE and applying similar Green's identities to the other terms, we obtain

$$
\alpha\left((\Delta y, \Delta  v) + \int_{\partial\Omega} v(\nabla\Delta u\cdot\hat{n}) - \Delta y(\nabla v\cdot \hat{n})ds\right) + (y,v) = \alpha^{1/4}(y_d,v) - \alpha^{5/4}\left((f+u_d,\Delta v) + \int_{\partial\Omega}v(\nabla(f+u_d)\cdot\hat{n}) - (f+u_d)(\nabla v\cdot\hat{n})ds\right).
$$
Collecting like terms, we obtain

$$
\alpha(\Delta y,\Delta v) + (y,v) = \alpha^{1/4}(y_d,v)+\alpha^{5/4}( f+u_d,\Delta v) \\
+\int_{\partial\Omega}\left(\alpha\Delta y +\alpha^{5/4}(f+u_d)\right)(\nabla v\cdot\hat{n}) + v\left(\alpha\nabla\Delta u\cdot\hat{n} - \alpha^{5/4}\nabla(f+u_d)\cdot\hat{n}\right).
$$

Because of the boundary condition $\alpha^{1/2}\Delta y + \alpha^{3/4}(f+u_d) = 0$, the first term in the boundary integral is zero. The second term is zero because $v\in H^2_0(\Omega)$. Therefore, your weak form reduces to
$$
\alpha(\Delta y,\Delta v) + (y,v) = \alpha^{1/4}(y_d,v)+\alpha^{5/4}( f+u_d,\Delta v) \quad \forall v\in H^2_0(\Omega).
$$

It's a bit late for me so I'm missing how to prove the bound right now but letting $v=y$ then using CS seems like it yields something like what you want.

Comment: Thanks! but how did you get the first green's identity? I tried to split the $\Delta^2$ but somehow ended in a loop thing.

Comment: Apply the second identity from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities with $\varphi = \Delta y$

Comment: still not clear to me how to end up with the inequality. is there any algebraic trick here? if we use elliptic regularity there would be a constant on both sides but not on the two terms together. and that $\alpha^{5/4}$ reduces to 1/8..